# How to loop through the form which has random elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through the form which has label inside random elements and check if the label matches with the given label name and if matches, I am adding a class to that element. But I am not able get it working, how can I do this?

Here's what I have tried.

Form which has labels inside random elements like div

```
<form id="grtform">
    <div id="section-1">
        <lable>Currency type</lable>
        <input type="text" name="currencyType">
    </div>

    <div id="section-2">
        <lable>Currency rate</lable>
        <input type="text" name="currencyRate">
    </div>

        <lable>Currency of country</lable>
        <input type="text" name="currencyCountry">

    <div id="section-3">
        <div class="formData">
            <lable>Currency due</lable>
            <input type="text" name="currencyDue">
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Jquery code:

```
$("#grtform").each(function(){
                var matchLable = "Currency due"
                var lable = $(this).find('label').text();
                if(matchLable == lable){
                    $(this).addClass('matchFound');
                }
      });
```

Comment: You've misspelled "label" as "lable" in a few places. In particular, you probably want the `<label>` element instead of `<lable>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need loop through lables, not against form

```
$("#grtform lable").each(function(){ // selecting all labels of form
                var matchLable = "Currency type"
                var lable = $(this).text(); // changed here too
                if(matchLable == lable){
                    $(this).addClass('matchFound');
                }
      });
```

In above code, this refers to currently iterating label.

After trimming a bit

```
$("#grtform lable").each(function(){ // selecting all labels of form
                if($(this).text() == "Currency type"){
                    $(this).addClass('matchFound');
                }
      });
```

Comment: @MithunRaikar This is a great solution. I would try to loop as few times as possible, so if you want to get the `input` value as well, loop the parent element and select its children instead of looping twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following way :-

```js
var allLables = document.querySelectorAll("#grtform lable");
for(var i = 0; i < allLables.length; i++){
  var matchLable = "Currency type";
  var lable = allLables[i].innerText; // changed here too
  if(matchLable == lable){
    allLables[i].classList.add("matchFound");
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="grtform">
    <div id="section-1">
        <lable>Currency type</lable>
        <input type="text" name="currencyType">
    </div>

    <div id="section-2">
        <lable>Currency rate</lable>
        <input type="text" name="currencyRate">
    </div>

        <lable>Currency of country</lable>
        <input type="text" name="currencyCountry">

    <div id="section-3">
        <div class="formData">
            <lable>Currency due</lable>
            <input type="text" name="currencyDue">
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```